# Let A be a self-adjoint, compact operator on a Hilbert space. Prove that there are positive operators P and N such that A = P − N and P N = 0.

Tags: hilbert-spaces, self-adjoint-operators

I'm having trouble approaching this problem. I'm totally unsure how to approach this problem.

Here's what I've tried so far: If A is self-adjoint, then $(A)^*=A^*$ and $(AB)^* = B^* A^*$.

Comment: Do you see what this proof would look like in the finite dimensional case?  Can we use the spectral theorem for compact operators here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** With the spectral theorem, we can write
$$
A(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty  \lambda_k \langle x,\xi_k \rangle \xi_k
$$
where $(\xi_k)_{k \in \Bbb N}$ is an orthonormal sequence (of eigenvectors of $A$) in $H$ and each $\lambda_k$ is real.  With that, define
$$
P(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty  \max\{\lambda_k,0\} \langle x,\xi_k \rangle \xi_k
$$

---

If you would like to avoid using the spectral theorem, then you could also characterize $P$ as $P = \frac 12 (A + \sqrt{A^2})$.

Comment: So to get $A=P-N$, my intuition is to let $N$ be the negative of the sum of the remaining eigenvalues, but that doesn't satisfy $PN=0$...

Comment: @kilojoules what makes you think that it doesn't satisfy $PN = 0$?

Comment: $P=\frac12(A+\sqrt{A^2})$ factor is missing

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I don't see why it should always equal zero

Comment: @kilojoules remember that $\xi_k$ is an orthonormal basis.  The image of $P$ is spanned by the eigenvectors corresponding to positive eigenvalues, and the image of $N$ is spanned by the eigenvectors corresponding to negative eigenvalues.  For any eigenvector $\xi$ corresponding to a negative eigenvalue, note that $P\xi = 0$.